# Save and load word embedding word2vec python

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embedding

I create and load a word embedding using this code:

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences,workers=4)
model.save(modelName)
model.wv.save_word2vec_format(vectorName+".bin",binary=True)

model = Word2Vec.load(modelName)
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(vectorName+".bin", binary=True)
```

Why, for example, this code produces different output?

```
print(model.wv.most_similar("woman"))
print(word_vectors.most_similar("woman"))
```

Outputs:

```
[('surprise', 0.529238224029541), ('cracked', 0.47902247309684753),..........
[(u'surprise', 0.529238224029541), (u'cracked', 0.47902247309684753),........
```

In the second one there is the `u` in front of all the results

Comment: u means Unicode. Which version of python are you using

Comment: @vumaasha 2.7.12

Comment: I think it's just a difference in encoding

Comment: Will it be a problem when I will do some operations? Should I always use model.wv that doesn't have this "problem"?